# The data reader is incompatible with the specified [X]. A member of the type

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and I am getting this error message when calling a stored procedure that inserts a record:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'SITHModel.Request'. A member of the type, 'ID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Exception is thrown at the return statement.

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Request> AddRequest(Nullable<int> routeID, string email, string description, string aDDEDBYID)
{
    var routeIDParameter = routeID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("RouteID", routeID) :
            new ObjectParameter("RouteID", typeof(int));

    var emailParameter = email != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Email", email) :
            new ObjectParameter("Email", typeof(string));

    var descriptionParameter = description != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Description", description) :
            new ObjectParameter("Description", typeof(string));

    var aDDEDBYIDParameter = aDDEDBYID != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("ADDEDBYID", aDDEDBYID) :
            new ObjectParameter("ADDEDBYID", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Request>("AddRequest", routeIDParameter, emailParameter, descriptionParameter, aDDEDBYIDParameter);
}
```

AddRequest is below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddRequest]
    (@RouteID int,
     @Email nvarchar(100),  
     @Description nvarchar(4000),   
     @AddedByIDnvarchar(128))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Request (RouteID, Email, Description, AddedByID, ChangedByID)
    VALUES (@RouteID, @Email, @Description, @AddedByID, @AddedByID)
END
```

I don't want the stored procedure to return anything and I'm not having issues with other similar models and stored procedures.

Controller

```
// POST: Requests/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,RouteID,Email,Description,AddedByID,ChangedByID,DateAdded,DateChanged")] Request request)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001";

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        }
            
        db.AddRequest(request.RouteID, request.Email, request.Description, userID);

        return RedirectToAction("ThankYou");
    }

    ViewBag.AddedByID = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email", request.AddedByID);
    ViewBag.ChangedByID = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email", request.ChangedByID);
    ViewBag.RouteID = new SelectList(db.Routes, "ID", "Name", request.RouteID);

    return View(request);
}
```

Any idea as to what I can update or remove to get this working?

Comment: new ObjectParameter("RouteID", typeof(int)) would add the type Int32 as parameter value, right? Maybe you wanted new ObjectParameter("RouteID", default(int)) ?

Comment: You are doing ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Request>, which means you expect function to return some rows which match some Request type. But as you said yourself - your procedure doesn't return anything, hence the error. Just use ExecuteFunction without generic arguments, and don't return anything from that method

Comment: I removed the return type and it makes sense, however I still get the same exception. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you need something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126767/the-data-reader-is-incompatible-with-the-specified-model ?

Comment: No luck with this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to remove this entity from my model, delete the controller, and re-add the entity and controller. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

As it is not part of the model and not required by the operation, try removing `ID` from the Bind attribute in the controller `Create()` API:

```cs
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RouteID,Email,Description,AddedByID,ChangedByID,DateAdded,DateChanged")] Request request)
```

instead of

```cs
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,RouteID,Email,Description,AddedByID,ChangedByID,DateAdded,DateChanged")] Request request)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteFunction<Request>` must have an output of type `Request`.

At the end of your stored procedure, write a Select that returns `Request` object columns.

The columns must correspond to the `Request` object class properties.

You can also skip writing generic.

Change

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Request>("AddRequest", routeIDParameter, emailParameter, descriptionParameter, aDDEDBYIDParameter);
```

to

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("AddRequest", routeIDParameter, emailParameter, descriptionParameter, aDDEDBYIDParameter);
```

But if you need result from stored procedure, first change stored procedure to

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddRequest]
    (@RouteID int,
     @Email nvarchar(100),  
     @Description nvarchar(4000),   
     @AddedByIDnvarchar(128))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Request (RouteID, Email, Description, AddedByID, ChangedByID)
    VALUES (@RouteID, @Email, @Description, @AddedByID, @AddedByID)
    
    SELECT * FROM Request
END
```

then use `ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction` with `<Request>`

```
  return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Request>("AddRequest", routeIDParameter, emailParameter, descriptionParameter, aDDEDBYIDParameter);
```

Comment: Have you checked the parameters without NUll?